# NextJs JSS Setup Error generating manifest Error: Unable to load manifest require

Tags: jss, nextjs

Trying to setup `NextJs JSS` and ran only the below simple commands and it fails with below error for the 4th command but this folder/files doesn't exist. None of the below 4 commands creates those files. What am I missing here?

1. `npx create-sitecore-jss`
2. `jss setup`
3. `jss deploy config`
4. `jss deploy app -c -d`

[image]

```
Error generating manifest Error: Unable to load manifest require D:\Sitecore\POC_Headless\nextjs\sitecore\definitions\config.js: Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Sitecore\POC_Headless\nextjs\sitecore\definitions\config.js'
```

Comment: Did you able to see the config files under zzz folder? After running the command `jss deploy config`?

Comment: @SumitBhatia Yes, I see the .config and deploysecret.config files in the app_config\include\zzz

Comment: can you check if you are in the right folder to run the command? I mean try running the deploy command under the folder that contains few folders and files. Like .generated, .next, data, node_modules etc?

Comment: @SumitBhatia the command deploy is being run in the root folder itself as you can see in the above snapshot in the description.  It is looking for a file \sitecore\definitions\config.js that doesn't exist so obviously one of the above command is expected to create these files or any other command is required before deploy command

Comment: Yes can you try the installation in another folder and check again?

Comment: Because in my installation I can see this file.

Comment: @SumitBhatia very strange, Tried in another laptop and multiple folders, did you use the same 4 commands from the description? I do not see this file

Comment: I checked, I was wrong, that was the order version.

Comment: @SumitBhatia Please recheck the above picture in the description, the instruction of this command "jss deploy app -c -d" is coming from the latest next js and latest jss version. It fails. See the suggestio provided while app creation by sitecore itself explicitly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally not clicking space will skip the manifest file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the Sitecore documentation, applications built with `JSS` for `Next.js` are deployed differently than apps built with `JSS for React`, `Angular`, and `Vue.js`. The document states the following.

Specifically, when working with `JSS for Next.js` remember the following:

- Do not use the `JSS CLI` commands `jss deploy app` or `jss deploy files`.
- Use `jss deploy items` for code-first item import.
- You do not have to configure a `sitecoreDistPath` in your `package.json` file.
- The Link and RichText field helper components support client-side routing out of the box.
- If you add `.graphql` files to your solution or make changes to your Sitecore data model (templates), you must update GraphQL introspection.
- The `Next.js` app is configured to proxy Sitecore media requests. Therefore, the Layout Service excludes server URLs.

For more information follow this document.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/200/sitecore-headless-development/sitecore-jss-for-next-js-differences-from-jss-for-react,-angular,-and-vue-js.html

**Features:**

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/sitecore-javascript-rendering-sdk--jss--for-next-js.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please recheck the above picture in the description, the instruction of this command "jss deploy app -c -d" is coming from the latest next js and latest jss version. It fails. See the suggestio provided while app creation by sitecore itself explicitly

Comment: The above description is also given in the Sitecore docs. If that is the case then I think a Sitecore support ticket would be a great option to identify the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@SNew

As @Sumit Bhatia suggested, select the template by clicking (entering) space and then run jss start, that will generate the src/temp/config file. Just now tried it and it worked just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Running `dotnet new sitecore.nextjs.gettingstarted -n <app_name>` without any parameters worked in my case